# Hiding referenced term name from node display

Tags: nodes, 8, taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I've stumbled upon a situation where I want to display a link and a custom icon for the link (I'm using paragraphs module) which will be themed correctly later, BUT. After providing a taxonomy term with a image field and making it display ONLY the image by default I'm still getting a h2 of the linked terms name.

I already tried hook_entity_view, but it doesn't have separate values for icon and the randomly displayed term name - only the term id meaning I cannot unset it at this hook.

Any suggestions/experience on how should we work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the content type or paragraph type go to *Manage Display* and configure the format of the term field as "Rendered entity".

Copy `taxonomy-term.html.twig` to the template folder of your theme and remove the linked title: `<h2><a href="{{ url }}">{{ name }}</a></h2>`

**taxonomy-term.html.twig**

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2><a href="{{ url }}">{{ name }}</a></h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the corresponding template?
To be sure just set debug: true in your root project services.yml file.
the inspect the HTML code with your web browser dev tool.

You should find comments like (just an example here):

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--title--reception-center.html.twig
   x field--node--title.html.twig
   * field--node--reception-center.html.twig
   * field--title.html.twig
   * field--string.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
```

Then find the corresponding template and edit it in order to hide the label.
In your case that template could be a field template or a term view mode template.